# Enhancing the performance of a for each loop that has an inner for each loop

Tags: android, kotlin

```
AS 4.1.1
Kotlin 1.4.10
```

Writing a for loop with an inner forloop to check stock items quantities. Checking if the item in the cart's quantity is greater than the current stock item's quantity.

Using a inner for loop seems to be a very naive approach even though it works.

Just wondering if there is a better way to do this:

For the curentSkuQuantity I have a data class like this:

```
data class CurrentSkuQuantity(
    val sku: String,
    val quantity: Int)
```

After RxJava return success with the current stock levels I check that the sku's are the same as the cart item. And then compare their quantities to see there is enough.

```
onSuccess = { currentSkuQuantity ->
                    val cartList = cartProvider.cdsCart?.items
                    var hasStockShortage = false

                    currentSkuQuantity.forEach { currentStockItem ->
                        cartList?.forEach { cartItem ->
                            // Check that we are checking the correct sku item
                            if(currentStockItem.sku == cartItem.sku) {
                                // Check the quantity is enough
                                if(cartItem.qty > currentStockItem.quantity) {
                                    // Not enough stock
                                    hasStockShortage = true
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if(!hasStockShortage) {
                        gotoCheckout()
                    }
                    else {
                        gotoCart()
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you said, the performance of nested loops could be better. The best way to match items of two lists is to convert one of them to a map, like what *Tenfour04* mentioned in his answer. In this way, the time complexity of the operation is reduced from `O(n*m)` to `O(n+m)` (*i.e* linear), where `n` and `m` are the order of lists sizes.

(`O(n)` for creating a map from `cartList` items and `O(m)` for iterating over the `currentSkuQuantity` list)

To achieve this, there are two beneficial collection operations:

- `associateBy`: to create a map from a list
- `any`: to check a condition over items of a list

Both of the above functions are of `O(n)` complexity and help us to achieve `O(n+m)`, in a simpler manner.

```kotlin
onSuccess = { currentSkuQuantity ->
    val cartList = cartProvider.cdsCart?.items

    val hasStockShortage = cartList?.associateBy({ it.sku }, { it.qty })?.let { map ->
        currentSkuQuantity.any { it.quantity < map[it.sku] ?: 0 }
    } ?: false

    if(!hasStockShortage) gotoCheckout()
    else gotoCart()
}
```

Note that the above snippet has advantages in **three** aspects:

1. reduction of overall time complexity from `O(n*m)` to `O(n+m)`.
2. `any` is efficient in terms of iterating over the list. So, it does not necessarily check all the items and returns if at least one element matches the condition.
3. if `cartList` gets null, `hasStockShortage` will become `false` and the time complexity reduces to `O(1)` (*i.e.* constant).

Answer (score 3):

For performance, you could break out of the loop once there’s a positive, although this doesn’t improve big O complexity. When you use `forEach` instead of a traditional for loop, you have to use labels to break out of it. But since you’re just resolving a Boolean, you can use the `any` function to immediately break out once there’s a positive.

```
val hasStockShortage = (cartList != null) && 
    currentSkuQuantity.any { currentStockItem ->
        cartItem.any { cartItem -> 
            (currentStockItem.sku == cartItem.sku) && cartItem.qty > currentStockItem.quantity 
        }
    }
```

But if you’re frequently looking items up by SKU, it would be a good idea to change the relevant list to a map of the items by their SKUs. Then you won’t need a nested loop. This would change it from O(n^2) to O(n).